# Rendering Open Sans font in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

I've got a problem with rendering Open Sans font in IE10. Font is rendered correctly in Chrome and Firefox. In IE text is rendered by default font. I've downloaded font from Google Fonts (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans). Here is CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Seems IE not working with .ttf font file, you can try to convert the .ttf to .eot using converter (you can google it 'converter .ttf to .eot'), upload it to your font folder and then try to use something like this :

```
@font-face {
font-family: OpenSans-Bold;
src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Bold.eot'); /* IE */
src: local("OpenSans-Bold"), url('fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf') format("truetype"); /* non-IE */}

@font-face {
font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot'); /* IE */
src: local("OpenSans-Regular;"), url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format("truetype"); /* non-IE */}
```

I have tried it, and it's working. Good Luck!!!

Comment: We can use [font-squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to generate different font types.